# React.js how to render random image changing state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple game: country flags are flashing one by one on the screen, and it stops on one particular flag after clicking on the button.

This is what I have so far:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


// CSS styles in JavaScript Object
const buttonStyles = {
  backgroundColor: '#61dbfb',
  padding: 10,
  border: 'none',
  borderRadius: 5,
  margin: 30,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  fontSize: 18,
  color: 'white',

}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { image: 'https://www.countryflags.io/US/shiny/64.png' }
    this.makeTimer()
  }

  makeTimer() {
    setInterval(() => {
      let countries = {
        USA: 'https://www.countryflags.io/US/shiny/64.png',
        Australia: 'https://www.countryflags.io/AU/shiny/64.png',
        "Puerto Rico": 'https://www.countryflags.io/PR/shiny/64.png'
      }
      let currentCountry = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Object.entries(countries).map(([key, value]) => <div>{key} <img alt={key} src={value}></img></div>)))
      this.setState({ currentCountry })
    }, 1000)
  }

  stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className='app'>
        <h1>where are you going on vacation?</h1>

        <div>{this.state.currentCountry}</div>
        <button style={buttonStyles} onClick={this.stopInterval}> choose country </button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

It does not work, all that renders is:

`NaN`

Before I added `Math.floor(Math.random() * ...)` it rendered all three flags at the same time, which is not what I want. Where is the mistake?

Also, I am not sure if the timer works correctly.

Comment: Didn't read everything, but `Math.floor(Math.random())` is always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't multiply a number (`Math.random`) with an array (`Object.entries(countries).map`).

You should create a helper function to grab a single element (or value) from an object if you're storing the flags in an object.

Also, you should never ever store JSX elements in your state. All you need is a URL, not a whole image element. You can store a random URL and update the image's `src` if the state is updated:

```js
const buttonStyles = {
  backgroundColor: '#61dbfb',
  border: 'none',
  borderRadius: 5,
  color: 'white',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  fontSize: 18,
  margin: 30,
  padding: 10,
};

function randomProperty(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return obj[keys[(keys.length * Math.random()) << 0]];
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentCountry: null,
      image: 'https://flagcdn.com/w128/us.png',
    };
    this.makeTimer();
  }

  makeTimer() {
    let countries = {
      'Australia': 'https://flagcdn.com/w160/au.png',
      'Puerto Rico': 'https://flagcdn.com/w160/pr.png',
      'USA': 'https://flagcdn.com/w160/us.png',
    };

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      let currentCountry = randomProperty(countries);
      this.setState({ currentCountry });
    }, 1000);
  }

  stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <h1>Where are you going on vacation?</h1>
        <img alt="" src={this.state.currentCountry} width="80" />
        <button style={buttonStyles} onClick={this.stopInterval}>
          Choose country
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid jsx in state.
Refactored your Math.random() code.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


const countries = [
    { name: "USA", image: 'https://www.countryflags.io/US/shiny/64.png' },
    { name: "Australia", image: 'https://www.countryflags.io/AU/shiny/64.png'},
    { name: "Puerto Rico", image: 'https://www.countryflags.io/PR/shiny/64.png' }
];
// CSS styles in JavaScript Object
const buttonStyles = {
    backgroundColor: '#61dbfb',
    padding: 10,
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 30,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',

}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { image: 'https://www.countryflags.io/US/shiny/64.png' }
        this.makeTimer()
    }

    makeTimer() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            const countryIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * countries.length);
            this.setState({
                image: countries[countryIndex].image
            });
        }, 1000)
    }

    stopInterval = () => {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <h1>where are you going on vacation?</h1>

                <div>{this.state.currentCountry}</div>
                <button style={buttonStyles} onClick={this.stopInterval}> choose country </button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got something different for you, I expect it helps you.

```js
let countries = {
    USA: 'https://www.countryflags.io/US/shiny/64.png',
    Australia: 'https://www.countryflags.io/AU/shiny/64.png',
    'Puerto Rico': 'https://www.countryflags.io/PR/shiny/64.png',
};

//I changed the object to array for better data manipulation.
const countriesArray = Object.entries(countries).map(country => {
    return { name: country[0], flag: country[1] }
})

//Getting random country index by its length
const randomCountryIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * countriesArray.length);

console.log("Set the current country: ", countriesArray[randomCountryIndex])
console.log("Set the random flag: ", countriesArray[randomCountryIndex].flag)
```

So after this you can check if user's answers match the current country on state

Answer (score -1):

Math.floor(Math.random()) returns zero!
use this:

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
```

Comment: OP didn't use `Math.floor(Math.random())` in their code but `Math.floor(Math.random() * somevalue);`, exactly what you're suggesting.